# Is it possible to port or migrate tripcodes from one server to another?

Tags: server, migration, des, crypt, tripcode

Specifically, I'm looking to determine if tripcodes for users on 4chan could have been migrated to 8chan, and then to 8kun.
My (limited) understanding of this mechanism is that each server creates its own unique hash table and therefore DES Crypt(3) tripcodes on one server could not be used on another.